# When page loaded Checkbox only check one time ? ASP.NET ,C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

My simple question is that ,is there any method/way in which 'Checbox' only check one time.I mean when page loaded which contains 'checkbox' ,after page loaded then i select check box and press 'button' then checkbox will be disabled,only one time checkbox will tick.Is there any way?
Thanks.
here is my code :

```
<label>Allow Null <asp:CheckBox ID="Null" runat="server" /></label> 
<label>Primary Key <asp:CheckBox ID="Primary" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ValidationGroup="s" onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Insert" />
```

I want when i press "Insert" button then primary checkbox(check its tick or not),if Primary cehckbox tick then next time this will be disabled.Only one time "Primary" checkbox tick.

Comment: You can try adding disabled attribute at your checkbox element

Comment: Yes, a click event handler on the button can disable the checkbox. No problem. Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

As the coments suggests ,
from client script you can try this:

```
$("#checkId").attr("disabled", true);
```

if you are in *asp.net web-forms* and the button does *postback* then you can even disable it from code behind.

*Edit*

```
<label>Allow Null <asp:CheckBox ID="Null" runat="server" ClientIdMode="Static" /></label> 
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" ValidationGroup="s" onclick="Button1_Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="UpdateCheck();" Text="Insert" />
    <script>
    function updateCheck(){
        $("#Null").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    </script>
```